# What does "uhh tight" mean in this clip?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the conversation up to 0:15 of this clip.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5tK0QULaPI

VANESSA: Woah, woah, woah, woah, baby. You sure you wanna shoot your full wad?

WADE: Uh… Tight.

VANESSA: Vanessa.

First the girl asks the guy if he wants to shoot his whole load, then the guy answers with what I presume is an adjective for a woman's body part, then the girl follows that with her name.

The whole conversation doesn't make sense to me. Are they just saying random sexual sentences to each other, or are those expressions commonly used in pairs in the US?

Comment: When she says her name, it is basically a new topic in the conversation, where they moved on to introductions (as he then replies with his own name). It is all a bit tongue-in-cheek, and reminds me very much of The Yorkshiremen sketch (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKHFZBUTA4k)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's part of a conversation including things like *What's a nice place like this doing in a girl like you?* ELU isn't the right site for people who don't know English very well, and that video clip isn't really suitable for learners anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Deadpool/Wade is trying to brush her off by giving a general slang phrase of agreement. The little finger linking is a general friendship greeting too, more common with kids and often seen in 'pinkie promises'.

> #### Tight
>
> The late 90's/2000 term for something that is cool.
>   Friend: "Dude, i got a new computer for christmas"
>
> Me: "Tight, dude!"

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tight)